# How to create subtable with tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a sub table with tableau desktop, here below is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I have a field named secteur, which contains all my secteurs, but I want to regroup them into 3 groups(secteur A-z, secteur G-P, secteur R-Z), which I have done until now was to create 3 groups, and 3 worksheets for each sous group, but what I want is to put those 3 groups into one worksheet instead of 3, does anyone have clue how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created a Group, then you can add that to your table. For example, you might put `[Secteur Group]`, `[Secteur]`, `<whatever that measure is>` into your Rows shelf, and it will break things down as expected:

```
 Secteur Group     Secteur   Measure
-------------------------------------
 VB-sectuer-A-F    Apples    20
                   Barbosa   56
                   Doge      15,236
 VB-secteur-G-P    Lemma     12
                   Pope      41
                   Pupil     25
 VB-secteur-R-Z    Rad       15
                   ZZZZZZ    349
```

---

But with that method, you have to create the group manually. There's a much easier way. Create a calculated field:

```
IF LEFT([Secteur], 1) <= 'F'
  THEN "VB-secteur-A-F"
ELSEIF LEFT([Secteur], 1) >= 'G' AND LEFT([Secteur], 1) <= 'P'
  THEN "VB-secteur-G-P"
ELSE
  "VB-secteur-R-Z"
END
```

By using `LEFT()`, you're using the first letter of each Secteur to automate that grouping process. Replace your Group with that new calculated field in the Rows shelf, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew LaPrise, i still have a question please, how can I add my group name for each group, like the part in red in my screenshot?Thanks in advance!

Comment: That calculated field is just returning the string of your choice. I updated my answer to return the string that I think you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry I might not explain my question quite well, I want to put my group name upon each group instead of putting it into as a column.

Comment: I definitely don't understand. Do you mean that you want a header row with no data in it, just a title?

Comment: Then the best way to do that is to make three separate worksheets. It's important to remember that Tableau is NOT Excel - it's a visualization tool. Everything is structured extremely consistently in Tableau in the spirit of good viz practices. Things that are very easy in Excel are frequently only accomplishable in Tableau through dirty hacks and silly workarounds. If it's necessary to lay out your table like this, you'll need to do it with three worksheets (as far as I know). If the column style can work for you, you can also shade the group column red, if that's an acceptable compromise.